# WSO2 proxy writing unlimited log files

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created a simple JMS to JMS proxy that listen to JMS from Glassfish sourceQueue and Send JMS to Active MQ targetQueue. Whenever I switchon the endpoint in WSO2 OR bring down the Active MQ and send a message to the sourceQueue, the system start writing unlimited log files that grows so quickly.

Here my proxy code and also underneath, I added the generated log file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JMS2JMSProxy2"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="ActiveMQ"/>
         </send>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Transaction Action" value="Committed"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Transaction Action" value="Rollbacked"/>
         </log>
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">GFQueue</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Here is the log file extract;

```
2014-05-07 16:22:52,451 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,451 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,457 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,458 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,458 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,459 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,467 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,467 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,468 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,468 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,476 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,476 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,477 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,477 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,485 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,485 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,486 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,486 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,494 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,494 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,495 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,495 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,500 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,500 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,503 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,503 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,508 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,508 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,509 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,509 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,514 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,515 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,515 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,515 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,523 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,523 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,524 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,524 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,534 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,534 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,535 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,535 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,540 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,541 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,541 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,542 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,547 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,547 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,550 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,550 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,556 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,556 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,557 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,557 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,567 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,568 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,568 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,569 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,575 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,575 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,575 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,575 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,583 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,583 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,584 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,584 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,592 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,592 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,593 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,593 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,601 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,601 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,602 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,602 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,608 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,608 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,610 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,610 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,615 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
2014-05-07 16:22:52,616 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  WARN JMS2JMSProxy Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
2014-05-07 16:22:52,618 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Rollbacked
2014-05-07 16:22:52,618 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy Transaction Action = Committed
2014-05-07 16:22:52,624 [-] [jms-Worker-9]  INFO JMS2JMSProxy FaultHandler executing impl:
```

Extract from Error log file;

```
2014-05-08 15:34:46,983 [-] [jms-Worker-1] ERROR JMSConnectionFactory Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : default using properties : {java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory}
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:629)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:319)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:425)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageSender.<init>(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.processThoughEngine(JMSMessageReceiver.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.onMessage(JMSMessageReceiver.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:535)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:438)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:401)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:53)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:263)
    ... 33 more
2014-05-08 15:34:47,138 [-] [jms-Worker-1] ERROR Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : default using properties : {java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory}
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:248)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:330)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:425)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageSender.<init>(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.processThoughEngine(JMSMessageReceiver.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.onMessage(JMSMessageReceiver.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:535)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:438)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:629)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:319)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:435)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:401)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:53)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:263)
    ... 33 more
2014-05-08 15:34:47,158 [-] [jms-Worker-1]  WARN ProxyServiceMessageReceiver Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
2014-05-08 15:34:47,228 [-] [jms-Worker-1]  WARN FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 0
2014-05-08 15:34:47,228 [-] [jms-Worker-1]  WARN FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
2014-05-08 15:34:47,228 [-] [jms-Worker-1]  WARN FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.processThoughEngine(JMSMessageReceiver.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.onMessage(JMSMessageReceiver.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:535)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:438)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : default using properties : {java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory}
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:248)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:330)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:425)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageSender.<init>(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:629)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:319)
    ... 29 more
```